# Streaming Flink SQL with GROUP BY over not timestamp column

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

In the [e2e Flink SQL tutorial](https://flink.apache.org/2020/07/28/flink-sql-demo-building-e2e-streaming-application.html) the source table is defined as a Kafka-sourced table with timestamp column upon which watermarking is enabled

```
CREATE TABLE user_behavior (
    user_id BIGINT,
    item_id BIGINT,
    category_id BIGINT,
    behavior STRING,
    ts TIMESTAMP(3),
    proctime AS PROCTIME(),   -- generates processing-time attribute using computed column
    WATERMARK FOR ts AS ts - INTERVAL '5' SECOND  -- defines watermark on ts column, marks ts as event-time attribute
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',  -- using kafka connector
    'topic' = 'user_behavior',  -- kafka topic
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',  -- reading from the beginning
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9094',  -- kafka broker address
    'format' = 'json'  -- the data format is json
);
```

As long as GROUP BY is made by a TUMBLE upon `ts` field, it seems natural (since Flink knows when to trigger / eject the windows) but in the middle of the tutorial we see the following expression

```
INSERT INTO cumulative_uv
SELECT date_str, MAX(time_str), COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as uv
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date_str,
    SUBSTR(DATE_FORMAT(ts, 'HH:mm'),1,4) || '0' as time_str,
    user_id
  FROM user_behavior)
GROUP BY date_str;
```

Here we see that GROUP BY is made on derivative `date_str` field, but how does watermarking works here? How does Flink decides when to "close" date_str bucket? Since `date_str` is some function over `ts`, it must somehow understand how the watermark update for `ts` would  translate into waterlevel for `date_str` field which seems unfeasable to me. How does it work internally, does Flink stores **all encountered records** in it's state?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can refer to the link below to learn about the generation and delivery of Watermarks, especially "How Operators Process Watermarks"

In this example, the watermark is generated from the ts of the source operator, and the downstream operator will only process the watermark, which has nothing to do with the date_str field.

```
public class TimestampsAndWatermarksOperator<T> extends AbstractStreamOperator<T>
        implements OneInputStreamOperator<T, T>, ProcessingTimeCallback {
......


    @Override
    public void open() throws Exception {
        super.open();

        timestampAssigner = watermarkStrategy.createTimestampAssigner(this::getMetricGroup);
        watermarkGenerator =
                emitProgressiveWatermarks
                        ? watermarkStrategy.createWatermarkGenerator(this::getMetricGroup)
                        : new NoWatermarksGenerator<>();

        wmOutput = new WatermarkEmitter(output);

        watermarkInterval = getExecutionConfig().getAutoWatermarkInterval();
        if (watermarkInterval > 0 && emitProgressiveWatermarks) {
            final long now = getProcessingTimeService().getCurrentProcessingTime();
            getProcessingTimeService().registerTimer(now + watermarkInterval, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(final StreamRecord<T> element) throws Exception {
        final T event = element.getValue();
        final long previousTimestamp =
                element.hasTimestamp() ? element.getTimestamp() : Long.MIN_VALUE;
        final long newTimestamp = timestampAssigner.extractTimestamp(event, previousTimestamp);

        element.setTimestamp(newTimestamp);
        output.collect(element);
        watermarkGenerator.onEvent(event, newTimestamp, wmOutput);
    }

......

    @Override
    public void processWatermark(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark mark)
            throws Exception {
        // if we receive a Long.MAX_VALUE watermark we forward it since it is used
        // to signal the end of input and to not block watermark progress downstream
        if (mark.getTimestamp() == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            wmOutput.emitWatermark(Watermark.MAX_WATERMARK);
        }
    }
......
}
```

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/